# Why is the whole module being loaded onto the page when we are using only a few things?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, node-modules

We have a design system which we package and install through node modules. We then import it through `next.config.js`

We use the module for all the pages, however we only use certain assets/parts from it. But after doing `npm run build:analyze`, it seems that the design system bundle contains the whole system on the pages.

What could be the reason behind this? I'm thinking we haven't been specific about something in the code somewhere?

Could anyone point me in the right direction on where/how can I find more info?

*I'm a junior btw, so apologies if I've said anything incorrect!

Comment: Does that module support tree-shaking ?

Comment: If you are using webpack, you might want to have a look at https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/

Comment: i think it does support tree shaking but the issue is that the design system is used by many repos, so if there is something in the DS that we are not using, it may be used by another repo of ours.

Comment: is there a way to bundle/load it without it loading everything onto the page?